# Using custom Alert Dialog box as a Form for Registering user in firebase database. Getting Error [kotlin]

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-alertdialog

I want to use custom Dialog box as Registration form for registering user in firebase database.i am already using Google signin option in this login activity.i've enabled the both the sign in method in firebase console still geting this error. Actually i don't want to use the activity because for that i need to move to another activity.. i want screen overlay like Ui. Please help me solving this Error or give any better aleternative in detail.. Thanks in advance

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@adc412
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
                [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
V/RenderScript: 0xb8012c38 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@adc412
```

> Login.kt

```
     lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private val RC_SIGN_IN = 1
    lateinit var googleLoginBtn: SignInButton
    lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var gso: GoogleSignInOptions
    lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var mProgressDialog: ProgressDialog

    var name1: EditText? = null
    var email1: EditText? = null
    var pass1: EditText? = null
    var confpass1: EditText? = null
    var loginT: TextView? = null


    var email2: EditText? = null
    var pass2: EditText? = null

    lateinit var mAuthStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)

        name1 = findViewById(R.id.editFullName)
        email1 = findViewById(R.id.editEmail)
        pass1 = findViewById(R.id.editPass)
        confpass1 = findViewById(R.id.editPassConfirm)
        loginT = findViewById(R.id.textL)


        email2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail)
        pass2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextPass)


        googleLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.gLoginBtn)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val emailBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.emailPasswordBtn)

        mAuthStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            if (it.currentUser != null) {
                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }

        gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)


        googleLoginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }

        emailPasswordBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@Login)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.register_custom_dialog, null)
            dialogBuilder.setView(view)
            val alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
            alertDialog.show()

            view.regBtn.setOnClickListener {
                //regDetail()

                val name = name1?.text.toString().trim()
                val email = email1?.text.toString().trim()
                val pass = pass1?.text.toString().trim()
                val confpass = confpass1?.text.toString().trim()


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    name1?.error = "Field Required!"
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    email1?.error = "Field Required!"
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
                    pass1?.error = "Field Required!"
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confpass)) {
                    pass1?.error = "Field Required!"
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }


                createUser(name, email, pass)
            }

        }
    }
```

> createUser() Function

```
       private fun createUser(name: String, email: String, pass: String) {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Registering..")
        mProgressDialog.show()


        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
                        val uid = currentUser!!.uid

                        val userMap = HashMap<String, String>()
                        userMap["name"] = name
                        userMap["email"] = email
                        userMap["image"] = "image"
                        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid)
                        mDatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

                            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                            }
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Authentication Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Authentication Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    // ...
                }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener)
    }
```

> register_custom_dialog.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editFullName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassConfirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPassConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Login using E-mail"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/regBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Register" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editFullName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Gradle Dependencies

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```